# What's the most reliable way to detect if the user is logging in from a different device than usual?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, browser

I suspect we're all familiar with how facebook and google and the like detect if you're using a different device than usual, I was wondering what the most reliable way to do this is?

I'm talking about the old 'It looks like you're signing in from a different device', and then when you confirm etc, it usually sends you an email and asks whether you want to trust this device or not.

Obviously one could just set a cookie, one that maybe get's checked and logged each visit, but what about when the user signs out? Do we keep the cookie?

Is there any other reliable method to 'trust' a 'device' other than setting cookies? Or is this the best/most reliable way to do it?

Comment: @Eric has provided a good answer, I'd also suggest checking the [Information Security Community](http://security.stackexchange.com/).They might also have some guidance

Comment: see also evercookie (mildly evil)

Comment: If you use techniques in Evercookie, be very careful in your privacy policy.  Companies were successfully sued over using some of the nastier techniques in there without proper disclosure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most reliable way to detect a device change is to create a [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) of the browser/device the browser is running on.  This is a complex topic to get 100% right, and there are commercial offerings that are pretty darn good but not flawless.  I worked at one of those companies several years ago.

There is now at least one open source fingerprinting project [Client JS](http://clientjs.jacks.io/).  I have not used it, but it seems to cover the bases.

Just setting a cookie is not very reliable because on average users clear cookies about every 30-45 days unless you use a network that attempts to re-set the cookie (paid services).  Even those are not flawless.

Just using the IP address is useless.  Some devices legitimately have many IPs in a short period of time (laptop at home, work and Starbucks or most any mobile device), while sometimes a single IP is shared by a large number of users (all the folks at Starbucks or behind a corporate proxy server).

**UPDATE**

Thoughts on your similar hash code.

It is a complex topic to get right.  I had a small team for a few years.  We got pretty darn good, but you can never be 100% accurate even when people are not intentionally trying to trick you.

- If the CPU changes, it's probably a different device.
- The same physical device can have many user agents.  Each browser on the device has a different user agent, and privacy mode of browsers have different user agents with far less entropy.
- Fonts doesn't change very quickly for a given physical device, though it's not a great source of entropy on mobile devices (few fonts installed, and typically all the same ones for a given type of device).
- OS is generally stable, until it suddenly changes.  Does it matter in your case if every device appears to be a new device when it updates to Windows 10?
- Color depth will be pretty stable.  If the user installs a new graphic card, this may change.  Does that matter in your case?

If you can accept thinking some devices are new when in fact they are the same and vice-versa, this type of similarity hash may work for you.  Note that you can never use this type of fingerprint to uniquely identify a device for a purpose that requires positive identification such as access to secure data.  It's great for making probabilistic decisions such as serving an appropriate ad.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea with Client JS - I'll wait to see if anyone comes along with more info for a while, but it looks to me like fingerprinting seems to be the right way to go. I'm guessing you then send a request back to the server with the client fingerprint and compare that to a stored value somewhere?

Comment: `send a request back to the server with the client fingerprint and compare that to a stored value somewhere`  Yes.  Note that devices can change slowly over time (or sometimes quickly), e.g. if you detect installed fonts and the user installs a font pack, the fingerprint will change.  Commercial solutions have algorithms to see if the change is "big enough" to guess it's the same or a new device.  Also different browsers on the same device can be tricky.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - it would seem that Client JS hashes the client data to create a fingerprint, meaning it would be hard to detect a similarity change...I wonder what algorithm could replace that, where similar inputs produce similar 'hashes'

Comment: I've tried mocking up a version that has a 'similar input > similar output' hash, what do you think? http://codepen.io/manticorp/pen/WQgBWq

Comment: Added a few thoughts.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated this to mark yours as the answer - I think the things you outline give a good idea of what would be required for different applications. Thanks for your help!