# How to prevent multiple login in SAAS application?

Tags: asp.net-core

*What I need to do*

I'm developing an application using ASP.NET CORE and I actually encountered a problem using the `Identity` implementation.

In the official doc infact there is no reference about the multiple session, and this is bad because I developed a `SaaS` application; in particular a user subscribe a paid plan to access to a specific set of features and him can give his credentials to other users so they can access for free, this is a really bad scenario and I'll lose a lot of money and time.

*What I though*

After searching a lot on the web I found many solutions for the older version of ASP.NET CORE, so I'm not able to test, but I understood that the usually the solution for this problem is related to store the user time stamp (which is a GUID generated on the login) inside the database, so each time the user access to a restricted page and there are more session (with different user timestamp) the old session will closed.

I don't like this solution because an user can easily copy the `cookie` of the browser and share it will other users.

I though to store the information of the logged in user session inside the database, but this will require a lot of connection too.. So my inexperience with ASP.NET CORE and the lack of resource on the web have sent me in confusion.

Someone could share a generic idea to implement a secure solution for prevent multiple user login?

Comment: Generally this isn't a problem, just use JWT (or reference tokes) and short lived access tokens. Also if its a paid service its not in the interest of the paying user to give away his credentials, since whoever he gives it to can access, change or charge to his payment information. You can never avoid credential sharing, even with two factor authentication. This is usually ruled via ToS/EULA and offending users banned (its their money they lose, not yours)

Comment: @Tseng An user can subscribe a paid plan for 100$, then it will give the access to other user for eg 25$ so these user will use the same account with a black market of license

Comment: Yea, but if you ban this users account for violating your terms of service, he gets nothing, the people who paid 25$ get nothing neither and are angry at the person who sold them the 25$ ones. in practice its an non-issue and account sharing is a violation of the contract and allows you to terminate it without any notice

Answer (score 2):

I've created a github repo with the changes to the default .net core 2.1 template needed to only allow single sessions. https://github.com/xKloc/IdentityWithSession

Here is the gist.

First, override the default `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>` class with a custom one that will add your session to the user claims. Claims are just a key/value pair that will be stored in the user's cookie and also on the server under the `AspNetUserClaims` table.

Add this class anywhere in your project.

```
public class ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(IdentityUser user)
    {
        // find old sessions and remove
        var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

        var session = claims.Where(e => e.Type == "session");

        await _userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync(user, session);

        // add new session claim
        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("session", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

        // create principal
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

        return principal;
    }
}
```

Next we will create an authorization handler that will check that the session is valid on every request.

The handler will match the session claim from the user's cookie to the session claim stored in the database. If they match, the user is authorized to continue. If they don't match, the user will get a Access Denied message.

Add these two classes anywhere in your project.

```
public class ValidSessionRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{

}

public class ValidSessionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ValidSessionRequirement>
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public ValidSessionHandler(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        _signInManager = signInManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(signInManager));
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ValidSessionRequirement requirement)
    {
        // if the user isn't authenticated then no need to check session
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return;

        // get the user and session claim
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

        var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

        var serverSession = claims.First(e => e.Type == "session");

        var clientSession = context.User.FindFirst("session");

        // if the client session matches the server session then the user is authorized
        if (serverSession?.Value == clientSession?.Value)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Finally, just register these new classes in start up so they get called.

Add this code to your `Startup` class under the `ConfigureServices` method, right below `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`

```
        // build default authorization policy
        var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddRequirements(new ValidSessionRequirement())
            .Build();

        // add authorization to the pipe
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = defaultPolicy;
        });

        // register new claims factory
        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>, ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

        // register valid session handler
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, ValidSessionHandler>();
```

Comment: @Dillinger I'm not using asp.net Identity but I'm just calling the database and comparing the session field to the one presented by the request. Updated to show my code.

Comment: It can remain empty. I don't use anything in the class. It gets passed to the `HandleRequirementAsync` method.

Comment: @Dillinger It works for .Net Core 2.1, that's where I'm using it. Give me a little while and I'll get a working sample out to github.

Comment: @Dillinger I updated my answer to reflect the code in the github solution.

Comment: is possible set another page instead of Access Denied?

Comment: @Dillinger This would be your best bet at the moment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1#cookie-settings

Comment: which are the correct folder to place your classes? eg: `ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory`

Comment: It doesn't matter what folder it's in. That's up to you. Just add the namespace to your `startup.cs` file.

Comment: I opened another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362575/authorization-roles-not-working-when-using-authorizationpolicybuilder/52364208#52364208 seems that with your solution the roles doesn't works anymore, could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UpdateSecurityStamp` to invalidate any existing authentication cookies. For example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid username/password.");
        return View();
    }

    if (await _userManager.ValidatePasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
    {
        await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
        var result = await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        // handle `SignInResult` cases
    }
}
```

By updating the security stamp will cause all existing auth cookies to be invalid, basically logging out all other devices where the user is logged in. Then, you sign in the user on this current device.

Comment: Okay, I tested your solution but for me didn't works. If I execute the login on the same account using different browser I can use the application without no log out. Also, I would like to create a blocking mechanism to the user that want log in, in particular if there is a session which already exists, I want to display an error message to the user that try to login with the same credentials like: "Hey, you need to log out from the other devices in order to connect". I don't think that a simple line of code can allow me to do that.

Comment: @Dillinger: That's not a very user friendly way to handle logins. I for sure wouldn't want pay for a such intrusive website. What if your other device is offline or at home? or your wife uses that machine at that moment. also what will you do if a user clears cookies? then from browser view he is not logged in, but from server view he is logged in. how can he log out to unlock the account? you are running against a wall with such an attitude and it does nothing to improve your applications security

Comment: @Tseng you're right, but the solution proposed by Chris doesn't work for me, maybe there is something missing? Because if I execute the login multiple times ther other session is still active

Comment: @chris, I'm using VS 2017 .net Core v2.x. I tried applying your code, it looked updating the 'concurrencyStamp' and 'SecurityStamp' columns in the table dbo.AspNetUsers. But it doesn't prevent from the 2nd, 3rd and so forth to login with the same user and password in other location/device. They all can login successfully. I opened a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645212/how-to-prevent-multiple-concurrent-login-in-net-core-2-x

Comment: The security stamp is only revalidated at an interval. It will take a few minutes for the user to actually be logged out. You can lower this threshold, even making it immediate, but it requires making more queries to your database. In particular, if you make it immediate, the DB will be queried each request to validate the stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to do something similar to what Google, Facebook and others do -- detect if user is logging in from a different device. For your case, I believe you would want to have a slight different behavior -- instead of asking access, you'll probably deny it. It's almost like you're creating a license "per device", or a "single tenant" license.

This [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551770/whats-the-most-reliable-way-to-detect-if-the-user-is-logging-in-from-a-differen) talks about this solution.

> The most reliable way to detect a device change is to create a
>   [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) of the browser/device the browser is running on. This is a
>   complex topic to get 100% right, and there are commercial offerings
>   that are pretty darn good but not flawless.

Note: if you want to start simple, you could start with a [Secure cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie), which is less likely to be exposed to cookie theft via eavesdropping. You could store a hashed fingerprint, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some access management solutions (ForgeRock, Oracle Access Management) that implement this Session Quota functionality. ForgeRock has a community version and its source code is available on Github, maybe you can take a look at how it is implemented there. There is also a blog post from them giving a broad view of the functionality (https://blogs.forgerock.org/petermajor/2013/01/session-quota-basics/)

If this is too complex for your use case, what I would do is combine the "shared memory" approach that you described with an identity function, similar to what Fabio pointed out in another answer.