# Authorization roles not working when using AuthorizationPolicyBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've implemented a solution which allow me to prevent multiple user session for the same account.

For doing so, inside the `ConfigureServices` method I added the following configuration:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SoccerForecastContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .AddRequirements(new ValidSessionRequirement())
    .Build();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultPolicy;
});
    services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>, ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
    services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, ValidSessionHandler>();
```

Essentially for each request the pipeline will call

```
public class ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>
{
  private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

  public ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<User> userManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
  {
      _userManager = userManager;
  }

  public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(User user)
  {
      var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
      var session = claims.Where(e => e.Type == "session");
      await _userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync(user, session);
      await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("session", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
      var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
      return principal;
  }
}
```

the class `ValidSessionRequirement` simple inherit that:

```
public class ValidSessionRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

now if I call this method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Customer, Admin, SuperAdmin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
{
```

I get: `AccessDenied`, but the user have as role `SuperAdmin`, if I remove the logic above all works as expected, any ideas?

Comment: You may be missing an `AuthorizationHandler` for your IAuthorizationRequirement.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1 for more info

Comment: @ozzy which auth handler?

Comment: In all the examples the `IAuthorizationHandler` is added as a Singleton.

I would recommend following the examples in this, especially the examples at the bottom which use Policy based role checks.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.1

The reason I say this is that you can easily turn off authentication & authorization using the IPolicyEvaluator when needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314486/2095110 for that.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Authorize` your `ValidSessionHandler` is being called regardless of what roles you apply to the method because its your default policy. You can add a check to skip certain roles in your `ValidSessionHanlder`. The code below will skip the session check for `Admin` and `SuperAdmin`.

```
public class ValidSessionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ValidSessionRequirement>
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public ValidSessionHandler(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        _signInManager = signInManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(signInManager));
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ValidSessionRequirement requirement)
    {
        // if the user isn't authenticated then no need to check session
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return;

        // get the user and session claim
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

        var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

        // get roles and skip check if Admin or SuperAdmin
        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        foreach(var role in roles)
        {
            if(role == "Admin" || role == "SuperAdmin")
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return;
            }
        }

        var serverSession = claims.First(e => e.Type == "session");

        var clientSession = context.User.FindFirst("session");

        // if the client session matches the server session then the user is authorized
        if (serverSession?.Value == clientSession?.Value)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, when I access to the page which have these attributes: `[Authorize(Roles = "Customer, Admin, SuperAdmin")]` it will redirect me to `Access Denied`

Comment: and also you have declared a variable `authorizationFilterContext` that you never use

Answer (score 0):

This is how to configure and what works for policy based authorization.

In `Startup` class configure policies

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... 
    // Configure security policies 
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("SuperAdmins", policy => policy.RequireRole("SuperAdmin"));
        options.AddPolicy("Admins", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin", "SuperAdmin"));
        options.AddPolicy("Customers", policy => policy.RequireRole("Customer", "Admin", "SuperAdmin"));
    });
    // ... 
    services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>, MyUserClaimsFactory>();
    // ... 
}
```

In your `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` you can add custom claims like this:

```
protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(User user)
{
    var userId = user.Id;
    user = await UserManager.Users.SingleAsync(u => u.Id == userId);

    // Add role claims
    var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);

    // Add custom claims for application user properties we want to store in claims (in cookies) which allows to get common values on UI without DB hit)
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName ?? ""));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName ?? ""));

    // Add your session or any other claims here if needed

    return identity;
}
```

In your controller authorization attribute shoudl use `Policy` name and look like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SuperAdmins")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
{ ... }
```

Comment: But the real question is: why I need to do this? and which folder the factory should be placed?